# Javascript (JsTree) : How to reference subelements of tree nodes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony1, jstree

Hi i'm working on a Symfony project and i need the JsTree structure to represent hierarchies from a database. I declare the `<ul> & <li>` structure espected by the JsTree libray correctly. Each `<li>` has its id = the id of the corresponding element in database, I put an `<a>` with its `href=[the url i need to use when click]`. Then i use the following function:

```
$("#myTree").bind("select_node.jstree",function(event,data){
    if(data.rslt.obj.attr("id")!=0){
        window.location = "myModule/myAction?id="+data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    }
});
```

The problem is that the link does not work as espected. When i click, window.location adds "myModule/myAction?id="+"the selected id" at the end of the route.

When i try more complex ways to indicate the new route to go to, for example `window.location = <?php echo url_for("myModule/myAction")?>+"/id/"+data.rslt.obj.attr("id");` then the representation of the tree fails: it does not show like a tree, just as a list.

I think it would be possible if there is some way to do something like that:
`window.location = data.rslt.obj.attr("id").subelement("a").attr("href");` then i could access to the information contained in the `<li>` field.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" is not the right kind of question. You should investigate more and be more specific. However, just examining your js code one can notice that you are propably missing quotes around php output where you assign it to window.location.

Comment: i have been investigating, but i'm new at javascript/jquery and i don't know where to do that. Except the "Am i doing something wrong?", i think the question is specific. The script shown there are no missing php quotes, if i add them, i have other errors (see `code portion 2`)

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle sample? I did not understand what you want achieve. Could you re-phrase it for me?

Comment: I'm asking if there is some way to access the elements contained int a nonde (<li>) of a jstree

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the answer. There is a function called `childNodes` that returns all the subelements of an object. I used the code below:

`var id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");`

`var child = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[1].firstChild;`

see documentation: [childNodes doc](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if you can fin the id of the < li> then you can obtains it's value by

var id =  data.rslt.obj.attr("id");

$("#"+id).val();

Comment: Is this suposed to return the things contained between <li> and </li> tags? A javascript/jQuery object with the common methods? I tried and seems to return nothing :S

Comment: it suppose to return the the value of id tag ,where <li> look likes <li id="someid"> ,in this case it will return "someid" in id variable